# Make This Pattern in Java (Nested Loops)

Tags: java, nested-loops

The idea is that you input in a number to start at and gradually decrease the numbers. Also, if you reach 9, the pattern starts back at one.

Example output 1:

```
11111 2222 333 44  5

11111 2222 333 44

11111 2222 333

11111 2222

11111
```

Example output 2:

```
7777 888 99 1

7777 888 99

7777 888

7777
```

Edit: Sorry, I didn't really have code because I didn't know what I was doing, but even though the answer's code wasn't right, it helped me start. Also, the numbers have to go down to 1 number at the end.

Here's my code right now that makes the first line:

```html
 public String makePattern()
 {
String output = "";
int amountPlace = amount; //amount is the imput
int amount2 = amount;

for(int i = 0;i < amount; i++)
{
  
for(int n = amount2; n > 0;n--)
{
 output = output + amountPlace + "";
}

output = output + " ";
amountPlace++;
amount2--;

if(amountPlace==10)
amountPlace=1;

}

return output;
}
```

I still need help making the other lines.

Comment: where is your code and where are you stuck?

Comment: Look at using recursion to solve this.

Comment: Would the task with numbers **increasing** in length seem easier to you?

Answer (score -3):

why not try this then

```
int numcount = 5;
string num_output = "";
for(int i = 0;i < 9; i++){
  for(int n = 0; n < numcount;n++){
    num_output += 'NUMBER TO APPEND';
  }
  numcount--;
}
```

Comment: 1) You're spoon feeding someone who hasn't even shown his code, something he's required to do per site rules, and 2) you're cheating him of learning how to code by doing this. Better to wait for his code, or he still refuses, then to give general advice that he can use and apply to create his own successful program.